# While running a powershell script using installshield, Enable-ADFSEndpoint can not succeed

Tags: powershell, installshield

I am trying to invoke a powershell script from installshield, but I am getting errors on the Enable-ADFSEndpoint line.

[image: my pic]

When I paste this script into powershell itself, it works properly.  But when running through install script's LaunchAppAndWait() function, it fails.  Here is my installshield code:

```
Param1=WINDISK +"\\Windows\\Sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe";
Param2="-ExecutionPolicy remotesigned -File \""+ INSTALLDIR +"PSServer\\Support\\adfs_cmdlets.ps1\""; 
LaunchAppAndWait(Param1, Param2, LAAW_OPTION_WAIT);
```

And the script code is as follows:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Adfs.PowerShell

#ENABLE ENDPOINTS
Enable-ADFSEndpoint –TargetAddress "/adfs/services/trust/2005/windows"
Enable-ADFSEndpoint –TargetAddress "/adfs/services/trust/13/windows"
```

There is of course more script than this, but upon execution through installshield, it isn't getting further.

I am very much so a novice at installshield, so any hints may help and are much appreciated.  Again, it is my current thought that the problem lays within installshield, because when my powershell script is invoked through the powershell command prompt, it works properly.  Thank you in advance to anyone that may respond.

I also realize it is likely that I have left out important information, and am of course willing to edit it back in upon request.

Comment: well it reads the file. what permissions are it running under? do you run your powershell console with admin rights while installshield runs without? If you run the script with `Enable-ADFSEndpoint .... -Verbose` does it output anything else?

Comment: The use of SysNative implies you're trying to run the 64-bit version of PowerShell from a 32-bit process.  Are you sure the snapin works in a 64-bit process?

Comment: @Keith, Thank you for your response!  Yes, I am sure that the snap-in works on 64-bit powershell because if we paste those lines into the 64bit powershell command prompt, they succeed just fine.

Comment: @Graimer The installer that contains this piece is being ran as administrator.  This makes me think that when this piece invokes powershell, powershell itself is also ran as administrator.  I assume this to be true.  We are about to run with -Verbose and will get back to you with any info :) Thanks for your comment!